# SwiftUI DatePicker does not always update State<Date> variable

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

For some reason `DatePicker` does not always update the date var associated with it. Am I doing something wrong? I can basically scroll around randomly and sometimes I can get to a point where my Text showing the current picked date (`var $entryDate`) differs from what the `DatePicker` shows that I have selected - my code:

```
struct addView: View {

  @State private var entryDate: Date = Date()

  var body: some View {
      VStack {
        HStack {
          Spacer()
          DatePicker("_", selection: $entryDate, in: ...Date(), displayedComponents: .date)
            .labelsHidden()
            .datePickerStyle(WheelDatePickerStyle())
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
            .environment(\.locale, Locale.current)
          Spacer()
        }
        Text("\(entryDate)")
      }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a known SwiftUI Bug.
I solved it with a little workaround:

```
@State private var refresh = false

      DatePicker("_"  + (refresh ? "" : " "), selection: $entryDate, in: ...Date(), displayedComponents: .date)
        .labelsHidden()
        .datePickerStyle(WheelDatePickerStyle())
        .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
        .environment(\.locale, Locale.current)
```

And at the end of your View:

```
.onReceive(self.$refresh) { _ in
   self.refresh.toggle()
}
```

Should even work with your labelsHidden().

Comment: using your suggestion results in: `Cannot convert value of type '(_) -> ()' to expected argument type '(_.Output) -> Void'`

Comment: Nice idea but does not work under iOS 16.2 and SwiftUI it seems...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround:

```swift
@State private var refresh: Bool = false

DatePicker("_"  + (refresh ? "" : " "), selection: $entryDate, displayedComponents: [.hourAndMinute])
                .datePickerStyle(.wheel)
                .labelsHidden()
```

Then whenever you edit `$entryDate` outside of the picker, call

```swift
self.refresh.toggle()
```

And the [DatePicker](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/datepicker) will update properly.

Comment: Nice idea but does not work under iOS 16.2 and SwiftUI it seems...